# Cloning two remote repos with the same data

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have a remote repo in GitHub and I have another remote in Heroku with the exact same data. I've started working through a new device and tried cloning both repos but can't find a simple way to do it. `git clone [repo name]` creates a new directory. So cloning from the second repo will be prevented it'll attempt to create a new directory of the same name. I could clone one repo, cd into it, and then clone the second one.  But it isn't ideal since I then end up with one repo with another repo inside of it.

For example, if my pwd is `Repositories/` and I do a `git clone` for GitHub I'd end up with `Repositories/MyProject`.  If I then cd into it and try a `git clone` for the second repo I end up with `Repositories/MyProject/Myproject`.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

> git remote add [repo name]' creates a new directory

No it does not. [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) only modifies the local config of the current repo (the `.git/config` file).

```
git clone /url/first_repo
cd first_repo
git remote add second_repo /url/second_repo
git config --local -l
git fetch second_repo
```

Then you can see all branches from both repos:

```
git branch -avv
```

If you want to clone two repo, simply do so from the same root folder

```
cd afolder
git clone /url/repo1
git clone /url/repo2 adifferentName
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `Repositories/` directory. Then clone first one (`git clone ...`). Now go into first repo and add a new remote (`git remote add <second>` ).

```
$ cd Repositories
$ git clone <first-repo-url>

$ cd <first-repo>
$ git remote add <second> <second-repo-url>
$ git pull second master          # pull the second repo's master branch changes
```